# Connecting two systems in a network?

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-vista

I'm trying to connect 2 laptops in a network

One laptop is installed with Windows Vista as Operating System and the other is installed with Windows 7.

1) Both of them are in one workgroup called "TESTING"

2) L1 IP : 192.168.1.2  Windows 7
   L2 IP : 192.168.1.3  Vista

3) When I try to ping L1 from L2, I'm getting a reply, but i'm getting "request timed out" in L1, trying to ping L2

4) I can able to see the shared folders and drives of L1 from L2, but i cannot see the shared folders of L2 from L1

Please can anyone tell me what is the problem I'm seeing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try running this command on the windows 7 box

```
    netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 disable
```

ICMP (the 'ping protocol') is blocked by default. If there was a network issue, you wouldn't be able to see shared files at all.

[More info here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if it wasn't a Windows Firewall issue on the Windows 7 machine, switch it off and test again. If it is the problem then simply reconfigure the FW to allow the rules you need.

Comment: Chopper, if u don mind...I don have a firewall
Both the LP's are connected with Wireless Router...is there any settings i should do with ?

Comment: Have you actually disabled the Windows Firewall on the win 7 machine, as it is on by default.

Comment: no firewall is ON on windows 7, but it was OFF in Vista machine
I juz made Windows firewall ON in both my LP's